# different sales_order_aggregated_updated vs sales_order_aggregated_created in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I began to learn about magento, but do not know the difference between this table different sales_order_aggregated_updated vs sales_order_aggregated_created? Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: When I refreshing report statistics orders, then magento insert into two tables sales_order_aggregated_updated and sales_order_aggregated_created with the same data, so i not know it used 2 this table to do? Similar to sales_invoiced_aggregated vs sales_invoiced_aggregated_order...